# what does this statement returns $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']

Tags: php, server-variables

```
<?php
 $string_message="what is meant by server_protocal";
  $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] ? print "$string_message<br />" : 
   print "$string_message\n";

?>
```

this piece of code is executing but I don't know why 'SERVER_PROTOCAL' is used and what does it returns.
thank you.

Comment: ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'
    Name and revision of the information protocol via which the page was requested; i.e. 'HTTP/1.0';](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `SERVER_PROTOCOL` is the transport mechanism that was used to request your PHP page. Normally since PHP is over the internet / browser, this will be the `HTTP` protocol. The PHP variable that you are printing will thus show you `HTTP/1.0` or `HTTP/1.1`. If the page was requested over `HTTPS`, then you will see `HTTPS` in your print message.

[image]

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php